# Firefox 3.6 end of life when?

Tags: firefox

When will be Firefox 3.6 end of lifetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me google that for you. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_3.6 ,

Firefox versions 4 through 8 had all reached end-of-life status while Mozilla continued supporting Firefox 3.6 with security updates. Coinciding with a proposal to cater to Enterprise users with optional Extended Support Releases beginning in 2012 based upon Firefox 10, Mozilla has tentative plans to discontinue support for Firefox 3.6 on April 24, 2012